# How to delay Laravel Job Queue

Tags: laravel, queue, laravel-jobs

I am trying to learn about Jobs and queues in Laravel , when i try to learn something new i always take a basic example by myself and try to  understand the workflow better.

Okay here is the problem

I have created a Job in Laravel as you can see in the handle method i am just trying to print a simple message on the laravel.logger , this works totally fine.

```
class SendEmailJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;


    protected $email;
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
       Log::info($this->email . '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<');

    }
}
```

My problem is that i want to delay this job for 2 minutes then to dispatch it ,
i have tried it this way but without success both logs are printed immediately when index method is being called but i want  `$job = new SendEmailJob("This will show after 2 minutes");` to be called after 2 minutes an not printed immediately

```
public  function  index(){
        
        $on = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(2);

        Log::info('Test');

        $job = new SendEmailJob("This will show after 2 minutes");

        $job->delay($on);

        dispatch($job);

        
        return "none";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#delayed-dispatching

You can do following: 
 `(new SendEmailJob("This will show after 2 minutes"))->delay(now()->addMinutes(2));` or 
`SendEmailJob::dispatch("This will show after 2 minutes")->delay(now()->addMinutes(2));`

Comment: It is printing **This will show after 2 minutes** immediately and not waiting for 2 minutes

Comment: that is strange, I was sure one of the 2 methods should work

Comment: Yes i have opened the laravel.logger file and it is printing both of them

Comment: It is not saving the queue in database though , it needs queue to be saved right ? at the job table

Comment: did you use the database driver?

Comment: I have added QUEUE_DRIVER=database but without success

Comment: I was not changing QUEUE_CONNECTION but  QUEUE_DRIVER lol . thankss

Comment: sometimes the little things bring much pain, glad it works